# How to introduce JavaScript alert window inside PHP code

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I need to introduce JavaScript alert function `show_alert()` inside PHP code. How this can be done?

```
script type="text/javascript">
        function show_alert() {
            var msg = "No solution found.";
            alert(msg);
        }
</script>
<?php
//...
    $outputs = -1;
    if ($outputs == -1) {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> show_alert(); </script>';
    } else {
        ?>
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="100%"> 
                    <div class="scrollbar" id="chart">
                        <img src="ganttchart.php">
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, it echos the show_alert(); in PHP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function show_alert() {
    var msg = "No solution found";
    alert(msg);
    }
</script>

<?php
//...

$output = run_function();
if ($output == -1) {
   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> show_alert(); </script>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried this code. Alert window doesn't pop-up. I tried to debug this code, but the cursor jumps over show_alert() line...

Comment: Try now, fixed $outputs to $output

Comment: Tested it locally with $output = -1; instead of $output = run_function();, works for me.

Comment: Well, if you say it works for you, I will accept the answer. For some strange reason I don't see alert box.

Comment: It's an issue with your run_function() function I think. Would you mind posting that too?

Comment: I think so too, http://meowman.sytes.net/js.php and http://meowman.sytes.net/js.txt

Comment: I do hope that you've noticed the $output = run_function(); and then you have $outputs == -1 ...

Comment: No,I don't think that's the function issue. Even if I write $outputs = -1; the alert message still does not occur, although I checked that the cursor goes inside IF statement jumping over echo line. I tried different browsers - Firefox, Chrome, IE.

Comment: It works for my given those links that you gave me. and the `outputs == -1` is in a conditional statement

Comment: Because it's supposed to be $output not $outputs?

Comment: `$output = run_function();
if ($outputs == -1) {` See what I mean? This is from your post. Either $output should be $outputs or viceversa.

Comment: Please look at my updated thread. Is it fine? If it is, then I wonder why it does not work.

Comment: I still think it's your function in PHP not returning the number correctly. Please post it maybe?

Comment: Yes, http://meowman.sytes.net/so/showalert/new1.php and http://meowman.sytes.net/so/showalert/new1.txt

Comment: When $outputs = -2; http://meowman.sytes.net/so/showalert/new1opy.php (I switched the img src because I do not have a ganttchart.php)

Comment: I putted $outputs = -1!! No need for my function. Still does not work.

Comment: Works fine for me... Can you give me a link to where you're hosting it?

Comment: It's on my localhost. Thanks for help. I thinks there is some other issue in my code.

Answer (score 6):

In-line JavaScript needs to be inside `<script>` tags. Simply output those as well, in a valid place. Do note that you cannot affect the operation of the PHP code this way though.

Comment: Could you give an example? I tried your suggestion,but probably I did something wrong.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: In what way doesn't it work?  Update the question to show the client-side code actually being rendered in the browser.  (Hint: If the indented code block isn't in the page source then `$outputs` doesn't equal -1.  Which means the code _does_ work and does exactly what it's intended to do.)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         show_alert();
    </script>
```

so like this

```
$output = run_function();
if ($outputs == -1) {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
             show_alert();
        </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't know why, but it doesn't work. Alert window should pop-up, but it doesn't. I tried to debug this code. Indeed the cursor jumps over show_alert() line...

Comment: does the if statement work? if u echo some php would it work? it might be that $output never == -1. But not sure - sorry

Comment: No,output is equal to -1. That's the case.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest

```
    $msg = "My message";
    echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\"> alert($msg); </script>";
```

You are right about it David

Comment: Your double-quotes are probably doing to confuse the parser and produce an error.

Comment: or just use 'text/javasript' instead since you are using the double quotes for the echo?

Comment: I think that double quotes (") are more xhtml like and I prefer them!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $output = run_function();
    if ($outputs == -1) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert("No Solution Found");</script>"
    }
?>
```

Comment: My answer is almost the same :/

Comment: Mine doesn't ask for a global function that was already defined in the Javascript. Instead, it just runs it without looking for a function

Comment: True, but he had the global function in his so I included that in mine.